# Need to limit the amount of data returned from an API using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm receiving some transaction data from an API. One of the items in this return is **buyer** which sometimes can be null. Therefore I'm omitting any buyers that have **null**. This creates a varying number of results. Ideally I would like to show 5 cards and if there is only 1 result, then I'll figure out some place holder for the 4 other cards. The problem is when I have more than 5 results because it will create an additional card. I'm trying to find a solution that will limit it to 5. I can't achieve this by altering the API filters because of this "buyer = null" condition. Is there anything that can be done using a styles file or any JS/React code that I can add that will allow me to max it out?

Currently I have not brought in the **Card** component and am working only with list items.

```
return (
    <ul>
      {highestBuy.map((result) => {
        const {
          buyer,
          price: { amount, token_symbol },
        } = result;

        if (!highestBuy) {
          return (
            <div>
              <Spinner />
            </div>
          );
        }
        if (buyer !== null) {
          return (
            <li>
              {buyer}
              {amount}
              {token_symbol}
            </li>
          );
        }
      })}
    </ul>
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several ways of doing this but there a moderately simple version.

```js
// test array of fewer than 5 items
const cardsA = [{
  buyer: "Adam"
}, {
  buyer: "Bill"
}, {
  buyer: null
}];

// more than 5 items
const cardsB = [{
    buyer: "Adam"
  }, {
    buyer: "Bill"
  }, {
    buyer: null
  }, {
    buyer: "Charlie"
  }, {
    buyer: null
  }, {
    buyer: "David"
  }, {
    buyer: "Ernie"
  }, {
    buyer: null
  },
  {
    buyer: "Frank"
  }
];

const makeFive = (cards) => {
  // filter out the nulls
  cards = cards.filter(card => card.buyer !== null);
  // make a new array to hold the cards
  const newCards = [];
  // loop 5 times
  for (let ix = 0; ix < 5; ix++) {
    // push a card from the filtered stack or a placeholder
    // card if the filtered stack is too small
    newCards.push(cards[ix] || {
      buyer: "default"
    });
  }
  // return the new cards
  return newCards;
}

console.log("cardsA", makeFive(cardsA));
console.log("cardsB", makeFive(cardsB));
```

Comment: Great! The only thing that is not clear to me is what you did in the **for(){}**. What could I look up to learn more of what you did here?

Comment: || [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) is the OR operator. {} [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) is an Object. So use the card or, if you've run out, add a default one.